# Use web application project and call it from Web site

Tags: asp.net

I already have one existing website project which is in production. Now i want to have another different functionality with set of new pages. So i want to keep another web application  project and refer the same in my existing website.

Button click in my website will call my webpage in seperate web application project.
 Am not using M.V.C

Is this possible? Can i host my newly creating web application along with my website?

I have tried to call webpage from website to my web application. It is working. But is this the correct way?

what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You can point your new domain to previously hosted website. Also you can use url rewriting to show whatever url you need to display to user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.How to point it. Can it be done using IIS manager?

Comment: You will have the option in control panel of your hosting/domain provider. I am not if you can do it through IIS but there can be some option for it in IIS.

Comment: Ok. But i am gonna have only one website. Placing new webapplication under the website. To achieve this, any configuration changes should i do?